# How to add new token to T5 tokenizer which uses sentencepieace

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, sentencepiece

I train the `t5` transformer which is based on `tensorflow` at the following link:

https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer

Here is a sample (input, output):

input:

```
b'[atomic]:<subject>PersonX plays a ___ in the war</subject><relation>oReact</relation>'
```

output:

```
<object>none</object>
```

However, for the prediction I get:

```
 ⁇ object>none ⁇ /object>
```

which replaces `<` with `??`, what should I do to resolve this problem?

**Update:** I found that strangely `<` is out of vocabulary for t5 tokenizer, which is `sentencepiece`, I just don't know how to add it

Comment: how about using regular expression?

Comment: @M.Innat i found that `<` is out of vocabulary for `t5` tokenzier, I just don't know how to add it

Comment: [Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068129/transformers-pretrainedtokenizer-add-tokens-functionality) good.

Comment: @M.Innat Thank you, however, I now added that I don't use Huggingface, but the T5 directly, which uses sentencepiece

Comment: I see. I think you should also update your title with more relevant words.

Comment: perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322462/how-to-add-all-standard-special-tokens-to-my-hugging-face-tokenizer-and-model?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can add new tokens using the Tokenizer.add_tokens(). More details can be found at huggingface [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/tokenization_utils.html#PreTrainedTokenizer.add_tokens.)

Comment: do you know how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322462/how-to-add-all-standard-special-tokens-to-my-hugging-face-tokenizer-and-model?