# After updating the tokenizer, LineByLineTextDataset keep on loading forever

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

After updating the tokenizer, when I run this line:

dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(tokenizer=bert_tokenizer, file_path="./some_file.txt",
block_size=128,)

it keeps on loading forever.

Here is the complete code:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM

bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

new_tokens = []
text = open("parsed_data.txt", "r")
for line in text:
        for word in line.split():
           new_tokens.append(word)   

print(len(bert_tokenizer))  # 30522
bert_tokenizer.add_tokens(new_tokens)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(bert_tokenizer))
print(type(new_tokens))
print(len(new_tokens))      # 53966
print(len(bert_tokenizer))  # 36369

from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset
dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=bert_tokenizer,
    file_path="./parsed_data.txt",
    block_size=128,
)
```

parsed_data.txt file contains simple text.

same issue was posted by someone before.
Link: github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5944

Comment: same issue was posted by someone before. Link: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5944

Comment: What is the size of `parsed_data.txt`?

Comment: 545 KB on disk. Yesterday I tested it and the loading continued for  1 hour 32 mins.

Comment: Transformers version?

Comment: tokenizers                    0.10.2        
transformers                  4.7.0.dev0

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this. Is `parsed_data.txt` confidential data or can you make it available for us? You can also send me a link via linkedin in case you do not want to share it via SO.

Comment: Btw. please also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073820/6664872) of @Jindřich regarding adding new tokens. Adding 5847 new tokens seems quite a lot (too many in my opinion when you just finetune bert-base-uncased for a few epochs) and will probably leading to a performance decrease if you do not conduct proper training of the newly added vectors.

Comment: parsed_data.txt contains just the text that I scarped from multiple websites. Yes I can share it with you. Can you please share me your Linkedin ID?